# Accesing a variable from another file

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I am using a string variable in a  class Abc , but i am not able to acces it in another class xyz.the value of variable is showing null. here is my skeleton of the code

```
public class Abc extends Activity 
{
 static  String strNew ;
.....
}

public class xyz extends Activity 
{
 Log.i("strPassword","strPassword is:"+Abc.strNew);
.....
}
```

the value of strNew is showing null , how can i overcome this problem.please help me out
thanks in advance

Comment: I think we need to see some more code.  How and when is `strNew` being populated?  What is your `Activity` lifecycle for the two `Activities`?  At what point are you trying to read the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You variable strNew is defined in the class `Abc` and not `AdminPwdParsing`. So you should use `Abc` instead of `AdminPwdParsin`g.

```
public class xyz extends Activity 
{
 Log.i("strPassword","strPassword is:"+ Abc.strNew);
.....
}
```

Additionally you have declared the variable strNew but you have never set a value. So the actual value is null. Somewhere in you code you have to set a value to your String:

```
strNew = "foo bar";
```

Another problem is that the visibility of your variable is package private. So it can only be accessed from within the same package. Set the visibility of the variable to public if you want to access it from everywhere.

Comment: @sameer I edited my answer. You have not set a value to the variable newStr.

Comment: actually my string variable strNew has the data . i am parsing a xml file and storing the value in the variable strNew.

Comment: @sameer Are you sure that there is really a value set? And it is before the Log is called?

Comment: ya im setting value like this                                 AdminPwdDataset StoredPwd = xmlHandler.getXmlData();
  strNew= StoredPwd.toString(); where StoredPwd has the parsed data and AdminPwdDataset is my class.

Comment: @sameer Ok, I can't see any problem.. Maybe with the full source code. But at the moment I can't see a problem.